# How to set path where to save CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, after-save

I'm saving records into CSV using after_save_filer. I don't receive any error and also I can't find file, what was generated(if it exists).

Here is code what I'm using:

```
 after_save :to_csv

 def to_csv(options = {})
  require 'csv'
  CSV.open("C:/project/myfile.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << self.class.column_names
  csv << self.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
  end
 end
```

How can I check is after save filter has been run ? How I can set the path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the after_save was run you can either put a `debugger` statement inside the to_csv method and see if it stops there when you save the model, or you could simply put a `puts "I am in to_csv method` inside the method and look for it in the console.